# Combine two lists to create a f(x,y,z)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have some experimental data as follows: The first list is a [f(z)](https://pastebin.com/Zkr0ZXWt), with z going from about -9 to 9 microns and the second list is a [f(x,y)](https://pastebin.com/nr3GSBsd) written in a form of a 100x100 matrix so the lines and columns go from -2.5 to 2.5 microns, as shown in the pictures [image: f(z)] [image: f(x,y)].

I want to multiply both functions in order to obtain f(x,y,z)=f(z)*f(x,y) something similar to this

[image: f(x,y,z)]

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to interpolate your function(s) (so it can be evaluated for the values of $x, y, z$ you don't already have sampled)?

Comment: ... since otherwise `f[x_, y_, z_]:= g[x, y] h[z]` seems plausible.

Comment: I don't think it will be necessary to interpolate but f[x_, y_, z_]:= g[x, y] h[z] is not working anyway.

Comment: I find it not quite clear, what do you have initially and what do you want to obtain in the end. Namely, you have a first list with the structure `lst1={{z1,f1}, {z2,f2},...}` and the second list presumably with the structure `lst2={{x1,y1,g1}, {x2,y2,g2},...}`. Now, what structure of the resulting list do you need to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d1 = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/Zkr0ZXWt", "TSV"];
d2 = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/nr3GSBsd", "Table"];

f1 = Interpolation[d1];
f2 = ListInterpolation[d2, {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}];

fn[x_, y_, z_] := f1[z]*f2[x, y]

data3D = Array[fn, {100, 100, 100}, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];

Image3D[data3D]
```

[image]